# Unable to search a Sharepoint List based on Column Name or List Name

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-list

I want to search for a sharepoint list based on the column name or the sharepoint list name. As of now, if i search by any of the values of the list (eg from below list: Elizabeth) i get the sharepoint list in the search result, but not for column name or sharepoint list name.

From the information i have gathered from different sources it seems like Sharepoint list column name and the list name are part of metadata and sharepoint search is not enabled to search on metadata.

Below is a sample list :

[image: Sample SP List]

Is there a way i can search on the column name of the SP List or SP List Name(eg from above list: Student Name or Test_SP_List)

Alternatively is there a way using python to download the metadata for all the sharepoint lists from a sharepoint site?

Sharepoint Site Version: 16.0.0.19513

Answer (score 0):

you should add a managed property "StudentName" on the correct crawled property in : /_layouts/15/listmanagedproperties.aspx?level=site

Add a search result webpart on your page, set the query as below

Path:https://yourSite/Lists/test_sp_list* StudentName:Elisabeth*

Comment: Thanks for the response @FredericDietrich . I am new to sharepoint so not quite familiar with the terminologies. Could you please let me know where should i add the managed property ? Also i want to just search by the column name and not the value so when i search StudentName in sharepoint i am expecting test_sp_list in the search result